# How to implement web api in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I want to implement web api services into joomla by passing parameters. I installed jBackend but what is next step after installation where to code for result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you, a Joomla component to create REST APIs: https://techjoomla.com/rest-api-for-joomla

Comment: Thank u i got extension from this link. I need example that how to implement it in joomla.